# Testing if a function works with dual

Tags: sql, oracle

So im rookie in SQL and working my way forward learning. And now I have stumbled across functions. The function is created but I want to test if it works, but dont get it to work.

Trying to create a function returning actual balance belonging to certain bankaccount nr.

```
create or replace function get_saldo(
P_saldo in konto.saldo%type,
p_knr in konto.knr%type)
return varchar2
as
v_saldo varchar2(20);
begin
select count(knr)
into v_saldo
from konto
where knr = p_knr
and saldo = p_saldo
and  p_knr = p_saldo;
return  v_saldo;
end;
/
```

Here's my test code;

```
 select get_saldo(p_saldo,p_knr)
 from dual;
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: *don't get it to work* is not a useful problem description. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: What is the value of `p_saldo` and `p_knr` in your final test query?

Comment: Unrelated to why your function isn't working (it isn't) but more related to your topic: Yes, this is a fine way to test the function by using `dual` like this. It's your function, not your test, that has the issue.

Comment: @Jnevill , that was my thought aswell, how do you correct my function to work according to that dual test? As Kristian below showed that Dual test did work. But I get small feeling that my function is incorrect anyhow.

Comment: I guess... it's the use of `dual` that's the problem. It's that you didn't specify values for the parameters that you used in the test. `get_saldo()` takes two parameters of the type `konto.saldo` and `konto.knr`. I have no idea what those are since that's your table and your data, but I do know you need to provide inputs to the function that match those types like `get_saldo(1, 'cat')` or whatever. In Kristian's answer he uses two numbers since that matches his made up `konto` table's definition.

Comment: So, if I were you, I would 1) Place some actual `saldo` and `knr` values in your function test `SELECT get_saldo(1, 1) FROM dual` and 2) If that still isn't working then come back here and give us some sample data from your `kanto` table as well as your desired results from this function and we can help out more.

Comment: Konto.saldo is = account.balance in english pretty much and konto.knr is account.banknr, to clear things up if that helps for you. I will test and return :)

Comment: SELECT get_saldo(1, 1) from dual; works but returns "GET_SALDO(1,1)
0" I did create a testtable, and entered knr(bankaccountnr) and saldo(balance) and put in data and tested my function, still gave me the results of "0" like before, and it feels like it should give me a balance instead, if this function is properly done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In your original question) we don't have test data, so it is not so easy to demonstrate (or debug) your function.  However, here are a few ideas ...

**Test data**

```
-- 2 columns: transaction (t_a) and knr (konto number)
create table konto ( t_a, knr )
as
select 100.00, 'AA001' from dual union all
select -10.00, 'AA001' from dual union all
select 200.00, 'AA002' from dual union all
select -20.00, 'AA002' from dual union all
select 300.00, 'AA003' from dual ;
```

For the function itself, we probably do not need to pass the "saldo" as parameter (since this is what our function is supposed to return ...).  We should probably adjust the return type.  Notice that the function depends on the konto table (even though this is a modified version here), which is probably not what you want (as this function will only work with the konto table).

**Function (modified, with comments)**

```
create or replace function get_saldo(
--  p_saldo in konto.saldo%type, -- <- we don't know the saldo, don't use it as parameter
  p_knr in konto.knr%type
)
return number                    -- <- saldo: a number, not a varchar2
as
  v_saldo number := 0 ;
begin
  select sum( t_a ) into v_saldo
  from konto                     -- <- the function depends on the KONTO table!
  where knr = p_knr ;
    -- and saldo = p_saldo       -- <- needed ?
    -- and  p_knr = p_saldo;     -- <- the account code will hardly ever be equal the balance
return v_saldo ;
end;
/
```

For testing the function, you can "select from dual", although behind the scences, a SELECT ... FROM konto is executed ...

**Testing**

```
SQL> select get_saldo( 'AA001' ) from dual ;

GET_SALDO('AA001')
------------------
                90
```

Always (always) use built-in functions if possible, as they have been thoroughly tested.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, very well explained aswell! May I ask what (t_a) stands for? I guess another column instead of mine "saldo"?

Comment: t_a stands for: transaction (the "saldo" being the sum of all transactions for a single account as it were ...).  That's why I thought that the example is a bit awkward, as we can use the built-in sum().

Answer (score 0):

OK - think you will get it to work if you try this

```
select get_saldo(0,0) from dual;
```

I've been testing it using the following table definition

```
create table konto (saldo number(10,2), knr number(38,0));
```

Then a copy of your function

```
create or replace function get_saldo(
P_saldo in konto.saldo%type,
p_knr in konto.knr%type)
return varchar2
as
v_saldo varchar2(20);
begin
select count(knr)
into v_saldo
from konto
where knr = p_knr
and saldo = p_saldo
and  p_knr = p_saldo;
return  v_saldo;
end;
/
```

And the test query from dual works as expected - but returns 0 - as I did not put in any rows yet

```
> SQL> select get_saldo(0,0) from dual; 
> 
> GET_SALDO(0,0)
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0
> 
> SQL>
```

Comment: It did work, thanks Kristian!

Question tho, in previous comments under my thread a user noticed that my function is rather incomplete. Is this your thought aswell? Any tips on correcting?

Comment: he he - its sees to me that you are testing a prototype just to see how it plays - but  yes - for example I would rather see my saldo as sum(v_saldo) for all konto I own instead of count(knr)